# How to Compile Different Sketches in Different Visual Studio Code Workspaces

Tags: compile, visualstudio

I'm using **Visual Studio Code** with the Arduino extension. I have two workspaces each with a different sketch file loaded - Sketch_1 and Sketch_2. Sketch_1 will verify and upload properly. When I click on the Verify to compile or Upload buttons for Sketch_2 in its workspace, VS Code verifies and uploads Sketch_1, not Sketch_2. Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible to separately Verify and Upload different sketches in different workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

The first time you verify your sketch you are confronted with a list of available sketches (INO's). As soon as you select one of these it gets stored under `"sketch"` in `.vscode/arduino.json`.
If you zero this, `""`, you'll once again be asked which sketch to set as "main sketch".

This "device context" is stored per workspace so you might consider narrowing your scope when opening a folder. I know this is no fun when exploring, and the will to switch and try different examples is big, but currently there are nothing that facilitates a smoother alternative.